# Calculate difference to the last date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to get the difference of the last date. For example `2021-03-22` until the next date (`2021-03-18`) it is 4 days. I want to calculate the difference in days between the row date and the last date for the `customerId`. So the complete calculation should be for each customer. And the last date should be `None` because I dont have any older date. The problem is that if the same date occurs more than once, the second date becomes `0`. It should look again at when the previous date was and not take the current date.

Dataframe

```py
    customerId    fromDate otherInformation
0            1  2021-02-22              Cat
1            1  2021-02-22              Dog
2            1  2021-03-18          Elefant
3            1  2021-03-18              Cat
4            1  2021-03-18              Cat
5            1  2021-03-22              Cat
6            1  2021-02-10              Cat
7            1  2021-09-07              Cat
8            1        None          Elefant
9            1  2022-01-18             Fish
10           2  2021-05-17             Fish
```

Code

```py
import pandas as pd


d = {'customerId': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
     'fromDate': ['2021-02-22','2021-02-22', '2021-03-18','2021-03-18', '2021-03-18', '2021-03-22', 
'2021-02-10', '2021-09-07', None, '2022-01-18', '2021-05-17'],
     'otherInformation': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Elefant', 'Cat', 'Cat','Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Elefant', 'Fish', 'Fish']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
df['fromDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fromDate'], errors='coerce')
df['lastindays'] = df['fromDate'] - df.sort_values('fromDate').groupby('customerId')['fromDate'].shift()
print(df)
```

What I have

```py
    customerId   fromDate otherInformation lastindays
0            1 2021-02-22              Cat    12 days
1            1 2021-02-22              Dog     0 days
2            1 2021-03-18          Elefant    24 days
3            1 2021-03-18              Cat     0 days
4            1 2021-03-18              Cat     0 days
5            1 2021-03-22              Cat     4 days
6            1 2021-02-10              Cat        NaT
7            1 2021-09-07              Cat   169 days
8            1        NaT          Elefant        NaT
9            1 2022-01-18             Fish   133 days
10           2 2021-05-17             Fish        NaT
```

What I want

```py
    customerId   fromDate otherInformation lastindays
0            1 2021-02-22              Cat    12 days
1            1 2021-02-22              Dog    12 days # from 0 -> 12
2            1 2021-03-18          Elefant    24 days
3            1 2021-03-18              Cat    24 days # from 0 -> 24
4            1 2021-03-18              Cat    24 days # from 0 -> 24
5            1 2021-03-22              Cat     4 days
6            1 2021-02-10              Cat        NaT
7            1 2021-09-07              Cat   169 days
8            1        NaT          Elefant        NaT
9            1 2022-01-18             Fish   133 days
10           2 2021-05-17             Fish        NaT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
df['fromDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fromDate'], errors='coerce')
df['lastindays'] = df['fromDate'] - df.sort_values('fromDate').drop_duplicates(['customerId','fromDate']).groupby('customerId')['fromDate'].shift()
df['lastindays'] = df.groupby(['customerId','fromDate'])['lastindays'].ffill()
print(df)
    customerId   fromDate otherInformation lastindays
0            1 2021-02-22              Cat    12 days
1            1 2021-02-22              Dog    12 days
2            1 2021-03-18          Elefant    24 days
3            1 2021-03-18              Cat    24 days
4            1 2021-03-18              Cat    24 days
5            1 2021-03-22              Cat     4 days
6            1 2021-02-10              Cat        NaT
7            1 2021-09-07              Cat   169 days
8            1        NaT          Elefant        NaT
9            1 2022-01-18             Fish   133 days
10           2 2021-05-17             Fish        NaT
```

Another idea is create helper DataFrame without duplicates, use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and for new column left join:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('fromDate').drop_duplicates(['customerId','fromDate'])
df1['lastindays'] = df1.groupby('customerId')['fromDate'].diff()
df = df.merge(df1[['lastindays','customerId','fromDate']], on=['customerId','fromDate'], how='left')
print(df)
    customerId   fromDate otherInformation lastindays
0            1 2021-02-22              Cat    12 days
1            1 2021-02-22              Dog    12 days
2            1 2021-03-18          Elefant    24 days
3            1 2021-03-18              Cat    24 days
4            1 2021-03-18              Cat    24 days
5            1 2021-03-22              Cat     4 days
6            1 2021-02-10              Cat        NaT
7            1 2021-09-07              Cat   169 days
8            1        NaT          Elefant        NaT
9            1 2022-01-18             Fish   133 days
10           2 2021-05-17             Fish        NaT
```